# What are the technical considerations for running MSSQL and MySQL off the same Windows server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Our application runs off MySQL, but a client has another application that requires SQL. We want to run them both on the same box. What are some technical considerations for this configuration... is this really just a matter of making sure there are no port conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will also contend for the hard drive, memory and cpu usage.  The first two more then the last.  If they are both actively used, they will both want to write to/read from the disk.  You may want to consider putting each on it's own drive *if* they are heavily used.

Test it out and see how the performance fares. For more details open performance monitor and take a look at the disk and memory stats.